# Can't close jedis successfully when I put it in the ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, jedis

I wanna keep only one instance of jedis in one thread, so I write a class refer to HibernateSessionFactory.

```
public class JedisFactory {

private static final ThreadLocal<Jedis> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Jedis>();
private static JedisPool pool;

static {
    try {
        Long timestampPre = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxWaitMillis(Constants.REDIS_MAX_WAIT_MILLIS);
        config.setMinIdle(Constants.REDIS_MIN_IDLE);
        config.setMaxIdle(Constants.REDIS_MAX_IDLE);
        config.setMaxTotal(Constants.REDIS_MAX_ACTIVE);
        pool = new JedisPool(config, Constants.REDIS_ADDRESS, Constants.REDIS_PORT, Constants.REDIS_TIMEOUT);
        System.out.println("TEST createJedisPool: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestampPre));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating JedisFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JedisFactory() {
}

public static Jedis getJedis() throws JedisConnectionException {
    Jedis jedis = (Jedis) threadLocal.get();

    if (jedis == null) {
        if (pool == null) {
            rebuildJedisPool();
        }
        jedis = (pool != null)
                ? pool.getResource()
                : null;

        if (jedis != null) jedis.auth(Constants.REDIS_AUTH);
        threadLocal.set(jedis);
    }

    if (!jedis.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "open jedis");
        jedis.connect();
    }

    return jedis;
}

/**
 *  Rebuild jedis factory
 *
 */
public static void rebuildJedisPool() {
    try {
        JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxWaitMillis(Constants.REDIS_MAX_WAIT_MILLIS);
        config.setMinIdle(Constants.REDIS_MIN_IDLE);
        config.setMaxIdle(Constants.REDIS_MAX_IDLE);
        config.setMaxTotal(Constants.REDIS_MAX_ACTIVE);
        // 创建连接池
        pool = new JedisPool(config, Constants.REDIS_ADDRESS, Constants.REDIS_PORT, Constants.REDIS_TIMEOUT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating JedisFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 *  Close the single jedis instance.
 *
 */
public static void closeJedis() {
    Jedis jedis = (Jedis) threadLocal.get();
    threadLocal.set(null);

    if (jedis != null) {
        jedis.close();
    }
}
}
```

It does keep one instance of jedis in one thread and work normal, but when I wanna cloes jedis by invoking closeJedis(), it throw exception.
And this is the info of exception below:

> [Details]redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not
>   return the resource to the pool   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:114)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:1)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.close(Jedis.java:3306)  at
>   com.lingxia.yueju.data.cache.AdCacheImpl.getAdByCity(AdCacheImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   com.lingxia.yueju.data.service.AdServiceImpl.getAdByCity(AdServiceImpl.java:172)
>     at
>   com.lingxia.yueju.app.controller.AdController.getBanner(AdController.java:50)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2407)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2396)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the
>   resource to the pool  at
>   redis.clients.util.Pool.returnResourceObject(Pool.java:61)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:111)  ...
>   41 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object has already
>   been retured to this pool or is invalid   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.returnObject(GenericObjectPool.java:582)
>     at redis.clients.util.Pool.returnResourceObject(Pool.java:59)   ... 42
>   more

Comment: The class works correctly. The exception must be caused by something else.

Comment: What version of Jedis do you use? Do you use Jedis instance with try-with-resources?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Jedis.close() disconnects when the instance is not pooled instance, and it returns instance to pool when the instance is pooled.

If you use Jedis with try-with-resources, your Jedis instance will be returned to pool when try statement ends. So when you call close() to return instance to pool explicitly, pool complains that instance is  returning twice.

So far, if you're trying to manage pooled instances on your own, you shouldn't use Jedis instance with try-with-resources.